# Registry keys handling 64 bit OS

Tags: c#, .net, registry, key

I am using registry keys to access the path of an XML file from installed folder of my machine.
My machine has 32 bit OS. So I am using

```
using (RegistryKey pRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Folder\subfolder\key"))
{
    if (pRegKey == null)
    {
        return;
    } 
    else
        // get path
```

But when I run it in 64 bit machine it is showing error, since I have not handled the exception case for 64 bit OS.

How can I handle it??

Comment: So where is the key on the 64-bit machine?

Comment: What version of .net are you using?

Comment: @Ic i am not having access to install it in 64 bit machine. Thats why i am confused.

Comment: Please start from here [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is 32-bit and you want to install it both on 32-bit and 64-bit OS, use this:

```
string regPath = string.Format(@"SOFTWARE\{0}AppName\Folder\subfolder\key", 
                      Environment.Is64BitProcess ? @"Wow6432Node\" : string.Empty());

using (RegistryKey pRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regPath))
        {
             .....
```

Comment: Thank you for ur interest..:) The main issue here is i donno the path part for 64 bit environment. Is there any default like Wow6432Node for 32 bit??

Comment: string.Empty() ??? so u r saying there will be like Software\Filder\subfolder\key in 64 bit machine?? will it run?? If the machine is not 32 bit then i have to read XML from 64 bit OS. so i have to traverse that path.

Comment: Sorry. You are running on `x86` OS and have `Wow6432Node` under `HKLM`?

Comment: yeah. am running x86 bit OS. and having Wow6432Node under HKLM. But what if i install my software in 64bit?? What will be its path??

Comment: If install 32-bit application on 64-bit OS you must add its key to `Software\Wow6432Node\AppName` if your app is 64-bit then add its keys to `Software\AppName`. See edited answer.